# ASP.NET MVC3 The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5

NET MVC3 with Entity Framework 5 (DB First) application and all of the access to the db raises the same error

```
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x2afc): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found]
   System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name) +6603626
   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) +106
   System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) +109
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname) +75

[Exception: Call to GetHostEntry failed after 00:00:00 while querying for hostname 'xxxxxxxx.db.1and1.com': SocketErrorCode=NoData, ErrorCode=11004, NativeErrorCode=11004.]
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname) +349
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetHostEntry(String hostname) +36
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStreamFromHost(String pipeName, String hostName, UInt32 timeout) +70
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout) +204
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +370

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +428
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +22
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +218
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +287
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +93
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +65
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +543
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +44

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +203
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +104
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +75
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +36
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +72
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +23
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   domvaproject.Controllers.PropiedadesController.Index() +21
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +311
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9628700
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

My hosting provider (1and1) tells me that the problem is mine, but i think that this problem is caused by some error in DNS. They told me that the error is in the code but it crashes on every connection

Comment: Have you tried connecting by IP Adress to rule out DNS Issuse?

Comment: I cant try this, website is placed on a shared hosting

Comment: Is your db and web hosting done by the same company? If not, you may need to specify the web server's IP address in list of allowed accessible IPs on the db hosting side.

Comment: Yes, my website and my db is on 1and1

Comment: Problem solved! The problem was the connection string that 1and1 gave me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error due to my connection string. It included a port number, but the correct connection string has to be like this:

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=password;Allow Zero Datetime=true" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```